# AS3 - Random swapping of height and width when rotating Bitmap object

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

Project : Game in Flex builder 4 (Actionscript Project)
Language : Actionscript 3

This code

```
trace ("--before-- "+sprite.width + "," + sprite.height);
this.sprite.rotation = obj.rotation;
trace ("--after-- "+sprite.width + "," + sprite.height);
```

prints this in debug console

!!before!! 72,13
!!after!! 72,13
!!before!! 72,13
!!after!! 72,13
!!before!! 72,13
!!after!! 72,13
!!before!! 72,13
!!after!! 13,72
!!before!! 72,13
!!after!! 72,13
!!before!! 72,13
!!after!! 13,72
!!before!! 72,13
!!after!! 13,72
!!before!! 72,13
!!after!! 72,13
!!before!! 72,13
!!after!! 13,72

Obviously there are 9 instances. So 18 lines output.
Please note that the width and height getting swapped randomly for some only.
Why is this happening ?

Comment: How do I close this. I found the answer.

Comment: Feeling stupid. Sometimes the rotation was 0 and sometimes 90. So its happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feeling stupid. Sometimes the rotation was 0 and sometimes 90. So its happening.

Comment: Thank Brian. I solved this, and it was happening because when you rotate a bitmap the width and height gets swapped. though the object is called sprite, its an object of Bitmap class.